# Automatically get Google OAuth2 token with cloud printing permissions if username and password is already known

Tags: node.js, firebase, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-cloud-print

I have a firebase app, everytime any user makes a suspicious movement, it needs to be printed. I'm trying to write a trigger on the server that can access cloud printing via the username "printerXXX@gmail.com" password "xxxx" that I have.

The google cloud printing needs an OAuth2 token in the authorization heading to access its printers. I'm trying to use googleapi node.js package to get the access token. However this means that I need a web front end, to tick "give googleappXXX permission to my cloud printers". Is it possible to do everything in the backend if I already have the password and email?